# Query to check duplicate value from table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a MySQL query to check duplicate values from table using MySQL and PHP. Let me to explain my table structure and conditions.

> db_product_info

```
pro_id     product_name      product_code      status
```

The above are my columns in `db_product_info` table.

> conditions:

1-> When table has no value the data should entry in table.

2-> In same product name only same product code will be inserted for once/multiple time in table.If input will different code for same product name (for more than one entry) it should be checked and return the validation message.

3- Duplicate of `product_code` will be checked according to the `product_name` as explained above.means for same `product_name` only same product_code should entry multiple time but this `product_code` should not used for any other `product_name` .

Let me show my code below.

```
 require_once("../include/dbconfig.php");
    $result=array();
    $fields=array("Product_name","status","product_code");
    $tablename=PREFIX."product_info";
$values=array($_POST['product_name'],$_POST['status'],$_POST['product_code']);
    $id=db_insert($tablename,$values,$fields);
                   if($id){
                $result[0]["msg"]="Added successfully";
                $result[0]['id']=$id;
                echo json_encode($result);
            }else{
                header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
                $result[0]["msg"]="Unable to add try again";
                $result[0]["data"]=$values;
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The adage "a picture is worth a thousand words" is very true here.  If you simply showed us sample input and output data, it would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : i need to check `product_code` value from table that why i explained clearly the conditions.If you understood it Can you please answer.

Comment: If you can't show us sample input and output, then I would wager that you don't understand the question fully yourself.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: am not getting you properly. i have already given my input values from client end and i need to check above conditions at the time of inserting data into table.

Comment: Wait...do you need help for a query, or is this a PHP coding question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : In this PHP coding i am getting the 3 input values from client end  for insert the data into table.Here my requirement is before insert the data user will check the above conditions and returns the message accordingly.I need those query here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98762/discussion-between-satya-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Following our discussion, I would say that you might want to rethink your table design.  MySQL (as well as most RDBMS) is very good at dealing with things like duplicates, and you should design should try to take advantage of this.  Having complex insertion logic in the PHP layer is undesirable IMHO.